# Install gettext to Apache2 on Snow Leopard Server

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, osx-snow-leopard

I have my web server from Apple installed on my Mac OS X server, and now I want to add "gettext" and more to the server but how can I do it?

I can't find php/ext/ folder, :/ and I don't know how I can get a new ext/ to work with Apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than monkeying with Apple's version (which they will update and likely break everything you modified), I suggest you check out [MacPorts](http://macports.org/) instead.  They allow you to [build Apache](http://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/MAMP) with variants to add the components you need.

Comment: Tanks i will try it, it is easy to install Apache, MySQL and PHP 5.3 on it?

Comment: Yes, it just takes a while to compile some pieces.  They're working on implementing binary installers.